# Which data binding option for large static list of objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and amazed by its powerful data binding features.  However, after reading numerous articles, I am not sure which option to use for my project.

===========
Project Details (involves viewing a locally stored tweet archive):

- The data consists of locally stored Twitter Tweets - more than 17,000 tweets stored in JSON format in a single file (no Internet connectivity used or needed for project).
- I am using JSON.Net to parse the JSON in the file and each tweet's dozens of JSON name/value pairs are assigned to a List of Tweet Objects (transforming each tweet's JSON data and into a Tweet Object).
- My program will use two controls to display the data.

**WPF control #1 (similar to a spreadsheet)**: displays in a grid pattern and text format each Tweet in rows (there will be 17,000+ rows of data).  Because there are dozens of fields, the user can choose which fields to display in a limited number of columns (5 or so) that will be visible (e.g., date, sender, text, etc.).  The user can search (via Linq), sort and select rows of tweets.

**WPF control #2**: displays each tweet selected in control #1 in the same format/appearance as it would have appeared in Twitter (e.g., nice color, the basic text, links, etc. in a small rectangle - Twitter publishes a standard for how tweets should appear).  If no tweets are selected in control #1, then it displays all 17,000+ tweets via scrolling.

Binding: When the user selects row(s) of tweet(s) in control #1, control #2 is instantly updated to show just the selected tweets in the nice graphic format, and vice-versa (i.e., select tweets in control #2 shows the selected tweet’s data in control #1).  There is also a calendar for selecting dates that will result in the associated tweets being displayed in control #1 and control #2.

I was thinking about using CollectionViewSource for control #1, however, that does not seem right because **the user never deletes or adds tweets to the List of Tweet Objects**.  However, trying to scroll, sort and keep everything running smoothy with 17,000+ of data rows and binding to the displayed tweets in control #2, may be too much for other options to handle (I do understand how some options can be virtual if necessary).  Perhaps DataGrid is the way to go?

====
**ISSUE: what should I use for WPF controls #1 and #2??**

Options for control #1 includes: CollectionViewSource, DataGrid, ListView, ListBox

Options for control #2 includes: ? ListBox to host images?

Thanks for your time, consideration and assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not editing then go ListView GridView (supports columns) and bind to List (now that List may be dynamic output form LINQ but still it is a List).  CollectionViewSource is not really about edit - it is about filter and sort - if you are going to use LINQ then why put CollectionViewSource in the picture. Multimaster A master of B and B master of A is a little out there - maybe rethink that logic.  With virtualiztion 17000 tweets can be done.